# Remove focus attribute on click Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with dropdown menus using Bootstrap. I created a border around the dropdown list item to make it look as if it's a tab. The border is only there on focus. The user clicks the tab to toggle it closed but the border still shows there as it's still in focus. How can I remove the focus after click?

[image]

Here's the CSS

```
    #refine2 .dropdown-toggle:active {background-color:transparent; border:0;} #refine2 .dropdown-toggle:focus {border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color:transparent;}
```

Comment: Could you please show the relevant css, html and javascript (if any) code?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I added the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Quick-fix: Set `outline:0;` in the css. This should remove the border.

Comment: I didn't say I had an outline, I wrote "border". The border I set in my CSS. Not the blue outline that the browser adds.

Comment: Added my CSS. The html is just standard Bootstrap markup.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old but you can solve this issue by putting the border on the list item instead.
  [Working example](http://www.bootply.com/9y03qs5fK3).

```
#refine2 .dropdown-toggle:active {
  background-color:transparent; 
  border:0;
} 

#refine2 .dropdown-toggle:focus{ 
  background-color:transparent;
}

li.dropdown.open {
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery, you could use

`$(".dropdown-toggle").blur()` to make it lose it's focus

**For example:**

---

**JS:**

```
var dropdown = $(".dropdown-toggle");

dropdown.on("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function(){           //loses focus after 0 milliseconds
    dropdown.blur();
  }, 0);
});
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
#refine2 .dropdown-toggle:active {
  background-color:transparent; 
  border:0;
} 
#refine2 .dropdown-toggle:focus {
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3; 
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3; 
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3; 
  background-color:transparent;
  }

#refine2 .dropdown-toggle{
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  li.dropdown.open {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7ys29c2/5)

---

Hope it helped :)

Cheers!

**EDIT:** I just saw this is a 7 month old question already... But I hope it'll still help someone else :)

Comment: Might update to fix the loss of the transparent background.